# How to sort(asc order) data(from database) in auto-complete drop-down in angular with custom Pipe

Tags: angular-material, ngfor, angularjs-orderby, mat-autocomplete

**app.component.html**

<input type="text" placeholder="data" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="organisationControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)='onOrgChange($event.option.value)'>
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions| async | sort: 'name'" [value]="option">
{{option.name}}

**app.component.ts**

```
1. import { SortPipe } from "../../../pipes/sort.pipe";
2. private sortPipe: SortPipe,
```

**app.module.ts**

```
1. import { SortPipe } from '../../pipes/sort.pipe';
2.@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        SortPipe
  ], 
   providers: [SortPipe]
```

Custom Pipe

**Shared --> pipe --> sort.pipe.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
export type SortOrder = 'asc' | 'desc';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort',
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, sortOrder: SortOrder | string = 'asc', sortKey?: string): any {
    sortOrder = sortOrder && (sortOrder.toLowerCase() as any);

    if (!value || (sortOrder !== 'asc' && sortOrder !== 'desc')) return value;

    let numberArray = [];
    let stringArray = [];

    if (!sortKey) {
      numberArray = value.filter(item => typeof item === 'number').sort();
      stringArray = value.filter(item => typeof item === 'string').sort();
    } else {
      numberArray = value.filter(item => typeof item[sortKey] === 'number').sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
      stringArray = value
        .filter(item => typeof item[sortKey] === 'string')
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) return -1;
          else if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) return 1;
          else return 0;
        });
    }
    const sorted = numberArray.concat(stringArray);
    return sortOrder === 'asc' ? sorted : sorted.reverse();
  }
}
```

Question: It is not displayed in ascending order. is there anything I missed to input?

Answer (score 0):

Provide proper arguments for your `sort` pipe having direction and the field name on which sorting is to be applied in app.component.html as given below:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions| async | sort: 'asc':'name'" [value]="option"> {{option.name}}
```

Refer the example of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sort-pipe-ioqzyr?file=src/app/app.component.html)